# LINQ "Left join" issue

Tags: c#, linq

I use the LINQ grammar try to implement a LEFT JOIN query, but the SQL shows it does not a LEFT JOIN. I don't know why.

```
public class WIPRepository: BaseRepository<WIP>,IWIPRepository
{public WIPDTO GetWIPByID(string wipID)
    {
        var query = from wip in _ronDaDbContext.WIPs
                    join product in _ronDaDbContext.Products on wip.ProductID equals product.ProductID
                    join user in _ronDaDbContext.Users on wip.OperatorID equals user.UserID
                    join station in _ronDaDbContext.Stations on wip.StationID equals station.StationID into stationJoin
                    from newStation in stationJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where wip.WIPID == wipID
                    select new WIPDTO
                    {
                        WIPID = wip.WIPID,
                        ProductName = product.FullName,
                        StationName = newStation != null ? newStation.StationName : "Unknown Station",
                        OperatorName = user.FullName,
                        CheckinDatetime = (DateTime)wip.CheckinDatetime
                    };
        return query.SingleOrDefault();
    }}
```

Below is the result in SQL Profiler, you cannot see "LEFT JOIN" key words here.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[WIPID] AS [WIPID], 
[Limit1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
[Limit1].[StationName] AS [StationName], 
[Limit1].[FullName1] AS [FullName1], 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[WIPID] AS [WIPID], 
    [Extent2].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
    [Extent3].[FullName] AS [FullName1], 
    1 AS [C1], 
     CAST( [Extent1].[CheckinDatetime] AS datetime2) AS [C2], 
    [Extent4].[StationName] AS [StationName]
    FROM    [dbo].[WIPs] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProductID] = [Extent2].[ProductID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[OperatorID] = [Extent3].[UserID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Stations] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[StationID] = [Extent4].[StationID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[WIPID] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'123'
```

Comment: Looks like EF 6 bug.

Comment: Please do not post code as images, post code as text.

Comment: Also have you checked with profiler if this is actual query which is run against the database?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, this is not a EF6 bug (How could be a bug in such important feature!)
How can I find the final reason, it is very easy, I setup a new individual project with EF6. and write a simplest similar function, it works (Generate LEFT JOIN) in SQL. Then I compare the DbConext that generate by EF. In my original project, I have modified the Database table several times, but maybe forget to generate new DBContext in one time, so the issue happens.